# Makefile:575: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o' failed

Tags: caffe

error message during install microsoft version when input command 'make all' on ubuntu terminal, i do not kwon why
Makefile:575: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o' failed

Comment: Can you please add the full build log?